# How to get a value in cascade selects with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I've go a list of **states** and **cities** like this:

```
var complejos = {
    'Buenos Aires': {
         '25 de Mayo': [],
         '3 de febrero': [],
         'A. Alsina': [],
         'A. Gonzáles Cháves': [],
         'Aguas Verdes': [],
         'Alberti': [],
         'Arrecifes': [],
         'Ayacucho': [],
         'Azul': [],
         'Bahía Blanca': []},
    'Capital Federal': {
         'Agronomía': [],
         'Almagro': [],
         'Balvanera': [],
         'Barracas': [],
         'Belgrano': [],
         'Boca': [],
         'Boedo': [],
         'Caballito': []}
}
```

In my code, I have two `md-select`, one to the user be able to select their state and after that their city. Example: Buenos Aires -> 3 de febrero.

I've got the following code:

```
<select id="state" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state, cities) in complejos">
    <option value=''>Choose a state</option>
</select>

<select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="field" ng-options="city for (city, fields) in cities">
    <option value=''>Pick a city</option>
</select>
```

Works fine, the only problem is that I cannot get the selected values. Instead I get the whole object with a "hashkey value" (`$$hashkey: object:116`).

How can I use that hashkey to search my result?

Comment: In which variable are you getting the hashKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second `<select>`, just change

```
ng-options="city for (city, fields) in cities">
```

To

```
ng-options="city as city for (city, fields) in cities">
```

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/woLt2zp4/)